# Testng.xml with multiple classes and multiple jenkins job

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have two different applications to test and they are two different classess. but the class EcommCreate1 uses diffferent url and Bocreate1 uses different url(url1 and url2).I have defined Jenking job with url parameters. but how to configure that EcommCreate1  should use url1 and Bocreate1 should use url2

So my testng was defined as

```
<test name="Order" preserve-order="true" enabled="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sw.testcases.EcommCreate1" />
        <class name="com.sw.testcases.BoCreate1" /> 
    </classes>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not break the 2 classes out into 2 tests and then pass in the parameter from the jenkins job.

Then in the class use that parameter in the driver.get(url);

Comment: I am using build.xml which will run testng.xml. Can you please explain how to use the parameter from jenkins job in testng.xml. I have modified my testng.xml to two different class and using <parameter name="EcommCreate1URL" value="jenkins_targetUrl"></parameter>

Comment: This is not working and throwing null pointer exception as URL value is empty